# How to type option + insert

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

In Youtrack (issue tracker) there are shortcuts that require 'insert' key which my macbook pro 15inch 2016 model does not have. How can I emulate it? Is there a combo like fn +  that simulates insert key?

I tried everything that was suggested in other questions and answers and have not solved my problem yet.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Option + Fn + Return?

Comment: @hexa yes, no luck

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is on Macs it will depend on the keyboard type. The different options I am aware of are:

- Do a **fn** + **return** keyboard shortcut
- Do a **fn** + **control** + **return** keyboard shortcut
- Press the **help** key

I do not know if any of these work on a 2016 MacBook Pro keyboard. I suppose you would have to try holding the **option** key as well as the above options to see if any work.

Comment: none of the above works on my keyboard

Comment: Did you try asking the app makers what they expect you to do on Mac?

Comment: @SašaŠijak I'm sorry to hear that. Did you find an option that works for you?